# AOS - how to not hiding the element again on scroll up

Tags: angular, animate-on-scroll

I'm using aos library in my angular project, and I attach it to the element

```html
<div data-aos="zoom-in"></div
```

it works fine, but my problem is, that when I scroll up - the element disappears, and scrolling down - appears again.

I assume this is the default behavior of AOS, so my question is - how can I change it? so when scrolling wherever after the element appears- it would stay there staticly and won't disappear.

Thanks you for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `data-aos-once="true"` as below to avoid the element disappearing when scrolling up.

```
<div data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-once="true"></div>
```

**Note:** By using `data-aos-once="true"`, An AOS effect will only work once.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it during init of AOS. Below should work for your requirement. `data-aos-once="true"` should also work as mentioned in the other solution. The approach depends on whether you need it on all animations or only of few elements.

```
AOS.init({once: true});
```